# Merge registry key by .vbs using GPO /computer configuration

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp-sp3, gpo

We have bought Team Viewer corporate, and need to deploy to our infrastructure, it includes Windows XP SP3, and Windows 7, our domain controller is Windows 2003 SP2, the setting of Team Viewer was exported to .reg file including the passwords and whitelists, I used the .vbs that Team Viewer provided to merge the registry values we exported earlier.
At a testing environment that matches the real environment, the deployment itself runs perfectly using GPO, but the script doesn’t run, if I tried to run the script manually by double clicking the .vbs file, I get “open file security warning” dialogue box, so I disabled it at the attachment manager by adding .vbs to the low risk list and everything worked fine, but the management refused this solution since it will endanger the network by marking all .vbs files as safe, and because it uses “user configuration” rather than using “computer  configuration” at GPO, why does this matter? Because users are mobile throughout the regions where we operate, and when a user logs in using their credentials they will trigger the script and the deployment which will affect the network bandwidth.
My question, is there any way to deploy Team Viewer and merge the registry file through .vbs using “computer configuration” at active directory GPO?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting article that suggests using .adm files (instead of .vbs scripts) to propagate a registry change to your users, using Group Policy:

- http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2007/08/14/deploying-custom-registry-changes-through-group-policy.aspx

Comment: This is great, but it uses logon scripts which is for "User Configuration" part of the GPO, what I really need is startup script which is for "Computer Configuration" part of GPO, for the reason stated above at the question.